# Il vocabolo "uxoricida" è frequente nella stampa italiana?

Tags: word-usage

L'autore di un articolo che ho letto recentemente in un giornale del mio paese si lamentava del fatto che la stampa spagnola non usa mai il vocabolo "uxoricida" (in spagnolo e anche in catalano si scrive in modo identico all'italiano, cambia solamente la pronuncia). Leggendo questo articolo ho subito pensato che conoscevo il significato di questa parola in italiano per averla letto in un romanzo di Leonardo Sciascia, ma non avevo idea se fosse usata o meno nella stampa italiana. Una semplice cerca su Google sembra indicare di sì, comunque non so si usa con molta frequenza. Potreste chiarirmelo?

Comment: @WalterTross perché non lo scrivi come una risposta?

Comment: @WalterTross: Sono d'accordo con I.M. Potresti scriverlo come risposta?

Comment: Femminicidio è una parola di rara bruttezza nata dalle manie di uguaglianza di genere, secondo le quali non si poteva usare uxoricidio, perché la parola "uxor" era discriminante. Esprime il concetto di moglie, non di donna.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Femminicidio* è da qualche anno una parola molto più usata di *uxoricidio*, e non soltanto perché il primo concetto comprende anche il secondo, ma anche perché la stampa da qualche anno ha (finalmente) puntato i riflettori sul problema, e quindi usa come parola chiave quella del concetto più ampio.

Credo che comunque *uxoricidio* e *uxoricida* fossero già da prima termini usati dalla stampa, ma non ad ogni occasione opportuna, probabilmente perché c'è sempre qualcuno che non li conosce (forse anche qualche giornalista, a giudicare dalle sgrammaticature che mi capita di leggere).

Answer (score 4):

Personalmente, l'ho letta e sentita spesso; forse, però, azzarderei a dire più di frequente in passato rispetto a ora, ma magari è soltanto un caso.

Comment: Benvenuta su Italian.SE, @MartaDM, e grazie della risposta!